# Windows Open file dialog search wildcards

Tags: windows-7

Using Windows 7 standard Open file dialog *(e.g. IE9>Ctrl+O>Browse... or Excel>Ctrl+O or Firefox>Ctrl+O)*, it is possible to search for files within the current directory - using the **File Name** box and pressing `ENTER`, e.g.:

```
*.txt
*2012*xls
*20??-12*
```

**Is this feature documented?**

I cannot find any documentation for the wildcard syntax or any official (or unofficial) tutorial or tips&hints page to give a link to users.

<sub>I tried googling https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=windows+open+file+search and the like, but I only got:

- programming tips for OpenFileDialog (does not count as a user-friendly tutorial)

- windows search feature (different syntax than in open file dialog)

- tech support when this feature does not work

- forums with broken links</sub>

Comment: It's just using [wildcard characters](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/find_c_search_wildcard.mspx?mfr=true) to search for files in an Open file dialog, which, if you think about it, _is_ a file search.

Comment: @martineau thanks for the Win XP link. I still would like to see it documented somewhere that you SHOULD be able to use wildcard characters in the **File Name** box. What Windows (other OS?) versions support it? How can I be sure this is not something special on my computer with all the 3rd party apps?

Answer (score 1):

The use of **?** and ***** as wildcards for matching file names is not new to Windows by any means. The wildcard matching algorithm used in Windows is based on that of MS-DOS, which of course inherited it from CP/M.

See for example *Raymond Chen*'s article titled [**How did wildcards work in MS-DOS?**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/12/17/6785519.aspx) for details.

Comment: thanks for the history lesson :) so you say this is just an undocumented left-over and is in all Windows versions known today?

Comment: Not sure if it's *specifically* documented anywhere that you can use those two wildcards in the standard File Open dialog. Might find something if you look hard enough, or perhaps it's just taken as a given because that's how file naming and wildcard matching rules have always worked, in *all* versions of Windows and back to their roots in MS-DOS and CP/M.